# Haskell Data Types

Tags: haskell, recursion, grammar, algebraic-data-types, recursive-datastructures

Which is not value of the Bin data types as defined below?

```
data Bin = B Bin | C [ Int]
```

a) `C [ ]`

b) `B ( B C [ 2])`

c) `B ( C [ 1..5])`

d) `B (B (B (C[2,3])))`

Comment: You could try to input the type definition and the different values in `ghci` to figure it out by yourself

Comment: I use hugs but i can not identify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `ghci` and simply inputing the code snippets you will see which of the values are accepted:

```
Prelude> data Bin = B Bin | C [ Int]
Prelude> a = C [ ]
Prelude> b = B ( B C [ 2])

<interactive>:3:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> Bin’
                  with actual type ‘Bin’
    • The function ‘B’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘Bin -> Bin’ has only one
      In the first argument of ‘B’, namely ‘(B C [2])’
      In the expression: B (B C [2])

<interactive>:3:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bin’
                  with actual type ‘[Int] -> Bin’
    • Probable cause: ‘C’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of ‘B’, namely ‘C’
      In the first argument of ‘B’, namely ‘(B C [2])’
      In the expression: B (B C [2])
Prelude> c = B ( C [ 1..5])
Prelude> d = B (B (B (C[2,3])))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ☺

Answer (score 1):

To easily answer such questions yourself, you need to comfortably understand Haskell's algebraic data type definitions:

```
  -- v  a type being defined
data Bin = 
           B  Bin 
        -- ^  ^ the type of the argument to the data constructor `B`
        -- ^ the name of the data constructor function `B`:  B :: Bin -> Bin
        --          (read: B is of type Bin -> Bin, i.e. a function
        --                 taking a Bin type value and producing a Bin type value)
         | C  [Int]
        -- ^  ^ the type of the argument to the data constructor `C`
        -- ^ the name of the data constructor function `C`:  C :: [Int] -> Bin
        --          (read: C is of type [Int] -> Bin, i.e. a function
        --                 taking a list of Int values and producing a Bin type value)
```

This means, we can create a piece of data of type `Bin` by using either one of two ways:

- First, we can call a function named `B` with one argument, a value of type `Bin`.
- Second, we can call a function named `C` with one argument, a value of type `[Int]`, a list of ints.

The second way is simple and clear: just use any list of ints, like `C [1]` or `C [4,3,2]`

```
x1 :: Bin        -- read: `x1` is of type `Bin`
x1 = C [1]       -- or,
```

But what about the first? We need to use a value of type `Bin` as the argument:

```
x1 = B x2
```

but where can we get `x2`? We are creating a `Bin`, and it wants us to give it a `Bin`? Is this a vicious circle?

No! For we have the second way of creating a `Bin` value:

```
x2 = C [2]    -- x1 = B (C [2])
```

But we could well use the first one here as well:

```
x2 = B x3     -- x1 = B (B x3)
```

and what about `x3`? By the same token,

```
x3 = C [3]    -- x1 = B (B (C [3]))   -- or,
x3 = B x4     -- x1 = B (B (B x4))
```

and

```
x4 = C [4]    -- x1 = B (B (B (C [4])))   -- or,
x4 = B x5     -- x1 = B (B (B (B x5)))
```

See? A valid value of the type `Bin` consists of a nested chain of `B` constructors, carrying a `C [...]`  inside, at the very bottom of the chain. Right? The data type definition serves as the grammar for producing valid terms of the type.

Now it is easy to answer your questions:

- `C [ ]` :   *- is this a chain of nested `B`'s with `C` at the bottom? :* __
- `B (B C [2])` :  *- is this a chain of nested `B`'s with `C` at the bottom? :* __
- `B (C [1..5])` :  *- is this a chain of nested `B`'s with `C` at the bottom? :* __
- `B (B (B (C [2,3])))` :  *- is this a chain of nested `B`'s with `C` at the bottom? :* __

This repeated application of the same rule is known as *recursion*, and this data type `Bin` is thus a *recursive* data type, with two clauses in its definition:  recursive clause, and the base clause.

Which is which?

Comment: Thank you so much ☺

Comment: you're welcome. so, which is which? can you tell? which clause in the data type definition is recursive, and which isn't?

Comment: Recursive definitiom

Comment: yes but it has two clauses in it - one for B, the other for C. which of them is recursive, and which is base case?